# How can I print String and int at once in text field net beans java

Tags: java

[image]

I want to print both string and integer at once in text field.

Comment: `tf3.setText(str + int1)`?

Comment: In future please ensure you post code as code not as an image.

Comment: @Jinx88909 ok....but why did you blocked me from asking

Comment: @Matrix I didn't. It's the site itself that determines what you can and can't do. I think you can receive temp blocks for a variety of reasons. Not sure why in this case but all activity is monitored. Your post came up for review being a new user and I left a suggestion for future posts. I didn't even DV your post.

Comment: @Jinx88909 do you know how can i get unblock from asking question.It's been 2 days since i am blocked...

Comment: Have a look on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days/271543#271543) or in Help which may give you an idea on how to find out. I was blocked for commenting and it lasted about a day. Think it was from deleting my own answers which I felt didn't help the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use string concatenation:
`tf3.setText(str + " " + int1);`

Comment: what about in new line i am trying Backslash character constant "\n" but its not happening  tf3.setText(str +"\n "+ int1);

Comment: @Matrix use `JTextArea` (instead of `JTextField`) if you want to include "\n" in the string.

Answer (score 0):

instead of two  tf3.settext();

do

tf3.setText(str + int1)